# Upload photo to fan page as a simple user (not admin)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Posting Photo to facebook fan page via iOS app by regular non-admin users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912901/posting-photo-to-facebook-fan-page-via-ios-app-by-regular-non-admin-users)

Does anyone has a full/working example for uploading a photo to a fan page as a user (NOT admin)? I can upload a video, but cannot make it work with a photo - very frustrating.

All I could find it's bits and pieces and no clear answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking for a solution to this as it seems to me that so far, the API doesn't support this functionality.

The workaround I've done is to upload the photo to the user's photo album first and then post the link to that photo to the Page's feed. It doesn't achieve the same effect as it only shows a thumbnail of the photo but it partially achieves what I want.

Perhaps this is by design so as not to have fans upload abusive content that gets posted on the feed but since the functionality is available on the facebook page, they should make this available through the API as well.

Comment: Same thing, man. Taking into account that from facebook interface you **can** do this, I consider it just as a hole in their api. Now doing same way as you do. After a whole lot of consumed time of tries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326463/facebook-upload-photo-to-fun-page-as-a-casual-user-without-administrator-righ/9326820#9326820