# Upload photo to Facebook Page as a user (without administrator rights)

Tags: android, ios, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Posting Photo to facebook fan page via iOS app by regular non-admin users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912901/posting-photo-to-facebook-fan-page-via-ios-app-by-regular-non-admin-users)

Is it possible to programmatically upload a photo to a Facebook page (community one) using Facebook Graph API? (Being not an administrator of this page) If yes, what HTTP request shall be made?

P.S.
Having administrator rights, I can retrieve the access_token of the page and upload a photo  (which will be marked as if page itself has uploaded this photo, not an actual user, since we're using the page's `access_token`);
Without administrator rights I can't retrieve the page's `access_token`; if I use the user's `access_token`, then the photo is being uploaded to **their** wall, even though it was marked *PAGE_ID/photos*, but not *me/photos* in the request.

Comment: @Igy: Emmm, I don't mind this question to be closed, but to mark it as a duplicate of the question you did ... actually that question was created 4 months later than this one, so technically *there* is a duplicate, or am I wrong? ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do this if you are not an admin of the Page in question. If you want to request this as a feature, you should file a [Bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) about it.

Comment: Would be great to know why you're so sure (like you're official representative or you know the official source). Not to say I don't believe you - I came to the same conclusion, but would be great to be sure. Right at the moment you mark the source, your answer will be approved. Thank you, Matthew!

Comment: Well, I can't link you to a source but the FB documentation doesn't mention the possibility that you can do this, so I guess it's the lack of a source that is the proof! Also, I tried it with a range of different pages and it always posted back to my own wall. There are a number of similar bugs already raised in the Bug tracker, so I suspect it is a previously encountered issue.